# Error: Cannot find control with name: 'billDate' with formBuilder and formGroup

Tags: html, angular, typescript, templates

I've been trying to create a form in with formBuilder and formGroup, this is the typescript file:

```
    constructor(
    private _userQueries: UserQueries,
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._userQueries.getCustomer().subscribe(({ data }) => {
      if (data) {
        this.customer = data.customer;

        this.updateInvoiceDates = this._formBuilder.group({
          billDate: [ this.customer.invoiceDates?.billDate, [Validators.required]],
          dueDate: [ this.customer.invoiceDates?.dueDate, [Validators.required]]
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

and in the template this is the form:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="updateInvoiceDates">
  <span class="subtitle">A continuación puedes definir las fechas de pago:</span>
  <div class="options">
    <span>Fecha oportuna de pago:</span>
    <div class="option-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field class="option">
        <mat-label>Día</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="billDate" type="number" min="1" max="31">
      </mat-form-field>
      <p class="option-text">de cada mes.</p>
    </div>
    <span>Fecha límite de pago:</span>
    <div class="option-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field class="option">
        <mat-label>Día</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="dueDate" type="number" min="1" max="31">
      </mat-form-field>
      <p class="option-text">de cada mes.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

dueDate field works like a charm but billDate is not working, returns: `Error: Cannot find control with name: 'billDate'`, and it's exactly a copy of dueDate's field. both the customerInterface and the getCustomer query returns billDate and dueDate, but only the second works.

Comment: Can you try to create demo in StackBlitz? From my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcdh3w?file=src/main.ts), it seems no issue. While it is weird that you bind a Date value into `<input type="number">` element.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps show the whole component code?

Also, could you try `console.log(this.updateInvoiceDates)`, what do you get?

You can try adding **novalidate** to your template like this:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="updateInvoiceDates" novalidate>
  //form content goes here
</form>
```

novalidate disables HTML5 form validation, which, sometimes can cause issues.